# How to import the template into a subdirectory of the templates folder in Flask?

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-restful

Currently I have an API project, based on flask-restful, with documentation page created with OpenAPI (Swagger). I'm trying to create a login page, based on my structure jinja2 can not find the path to the template.

In the login script, I tried to pass the full path to the .html file, in the `render_template()` function, but did not find the file. Just like adding the parameter `template_folder = path/to/file` in `app=Flask(__name__)` and I did not succeed.

**My Structure:**

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── login.py
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── jwt.py
│   │   ├── request.py
│   │   └── utils.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── core.py
│   │   └── db_app_2.py
│   ├── routes
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── resources.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── docs
│       │   ├── swagger.json
│       │   └── swagger.yaml
│       └── pages
│           ├── base.html
│           ├── login.html
│           └── signup.html
├── app.db
├── config.py
├── main.py
├── migrations
├── requeriments
└── tests
```

**login.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for
from app.models.core import db

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)


@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')


@auth.route('/signup')
def signup():
    return render_template('signup.html')
```

**__init__.py(main project)**

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_restful import Api

from config import config

from .models.core import db
from .routes.resources import TwoThings


def create_app(config_name):

    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="/templates/pages")

    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    '''Fixed path for routes the api'''
    path_prefix = '/api/v1'

    api_bp = Blueprint(path_prefix, __name__)
    api = Api(api_bp)

    from app.auth.login import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint, url_prefix=path_prefix)

    api.add_resource(Reset, f'{path_prefix}/two_things')
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp)

    db.init_app(app)
    Migrate(app, db)

    return app
```

I need to create a login page, to be accessible by the browser and once logged in redirect to the documentation endpoint.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
return render_template('pages/login.html')
```

In your `login.py`.